# Error: Yii::app()->user->id as $id function parameter

Tags: php, yii

What is the right way to use `Yii::app()->user->id` as `$id` function parameter?

Code:

```
public function actionUpdate($id=Yii::app()->user->id)
```

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in .../UserController.php on line 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) about function arguments

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.

You cannot declare function like

```
public function actionUpdate($id=Yii::app()->user->id)
```

You should initalise variable in function body, or class constructor etc.

Comment: Ahh, how can I solve since I can not declare this way? Declare null then check it? `if($id==null) $id=Yii::app()->user->id;`

Comment: you don't have to declare it at all, you can initialise it directly in the function body with `$id = Yii::app()->user->id;`

Comment: But I want `id` to be `Yii::app()->user->id;` only as default value.

Comment: Hmm found on PHP Docs! `$id = is_null($id) ? Yii::app()->user->id : $id;`

Comment: tips:  `$id === null` is more fast than `is_null($id)`